# MVC2 post model to action

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am posting the model from the strongly partial view to the controller like this:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
[Authorize]
public string ProcessRequest(Request request)
{
.
.
.
```

However, the model arrives to the action but it's incomplete, i.e. complex properties of the request are null.

I am sending the complete model to the view from another action, change properties and post to ProcessRequest action, which receives the incomplete stuff.

Does anyone know what could be the issue here?

Thanks!

The View declaration:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<Models.Request>" %>...
```

The property binding:

```
<% using (Ajax.BeginForm("ProcessRequest", Model, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "post" }, new { id = "ajaxForm" }))
    {%>

    <%= Html.TextArea("ReplyContent", Model.Reply.ReplyContent, new { cols="100"})%><br />...
```

Comment: Can we see your Model object and the View.

Comment: You should also check the post parameters with firebug or any similar tool. That usually tells you where the problem might be.

Comment: Both, the view and the model are quite large to fit in here. However, I am posting the relevant bits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, what MVC does is get the values of all the inputs of the form being submited, and all params from the URL, create a new object of the type you expect to receive, and assign its values.

So, let's say the form has the inputs "FirstName", "LastName" and "PhoneNumber". What would happen in your action is equivalent to this:

```
Request request = new Request();
request.FirstName = ReceivedValues["FirstName"] // Note that this is pseudocode, I'm making up the name for the "ReceivedValues" dictionary
request.LastName = ReceivedValues["LastName"]
(...)
```

And that's what you would get in the request object (obviously, any values received that don't exist in the model won't be assigned).

No matter what your original model included when you sent it to the View, once it's gone to the browser, and back to your action (after Posting the form), only those values that are received persist (you can see what values the action is receiving simply by using Firebug to inspect the contents of your post action).

Thus, anything not received from the browser, is null.

P.D. Note: I took from your question that you are beginning with MVC, if you actually knew everything I said and are having a more complex problem, sorry! :P

Comment: Hi, I would say that I am at the intermediate level with MVC. I learn as I go (have no time) and was under the impression that MVC will actually serialize the passed model, regardless of the fact if some property was bound at the form. Based on all of that, how would I include the information from the Request's Complex property, which is bound to Html.TextArea...? The request travels to the view with the Reply complex property (a class). The Model.Request.Reply is bound to the TextArea. How can I post the Request + Reply? Thanks!

Comment: Hehehe, yeah, you are not the only one learning as you go ^^. I don't quite get what you are trying to accomplish, but I usually store data not sent to the page either in session variables (have a look at the TempData and Session dictionaries available in the action controller) or directly in the database, and program the model to retrieve it depending on the values received from the browser (i.e. I receive replyId = 1, and add a loadReply() to the model object that gets the related record from disk).

Comment: P.S. Also, take into account that you can create an input field for "Request.Reply", and it's value would be sent back to the Action. You can not only receive direct properties of the Model, but also properties for properties of the Model that are also objects.

Comment: Hi, how would I do that, to create an input field for Request.Reply? Request is a class whose property is Reply which is also a class. When I load Request from the DB, the Reply gets loaded as well as a part of the Request class (EF 4.0. POCO). Then I bind the direct 'simple' properties of the request to various controls and also bind the Request.Reply.ReplyContent to the TextArea control. WHat frustrates me is that Action receives the Request but it's property of Reply is null :( My goal is to retrieve the Request whose property Reply is not null.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that Reply was a simple property, not a Class. You could include fields for the properties of that class (ex. Request.Reply.Subject) and a Reply object would be initialize and it's Subject value assigned. P.S. Take into account that, whatever you receive, it's now disconnected from your datacontext. If you are modifying a record, get the record again in your controller, and use the UpdateModel method to update the properties of your record with the values received from the browser (you'll have the reply available, as an added benefit).

Comment: Doh! I see bellow that you discovered my mistake ^^. Sorry for the late response!

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer to my agony:

```
<%= Html.TextAreaFor(m=>m.Reply.ReplyContent, new { cols = "100" })%>
```

Now, the Reply travels to the Action as a property of the Request.

After some research, I have discovered that the problem lies in the naming convention, i.e. the following is wrong:

```
<%= Html.TextArea("ReplyContent", Model.Reply.ReplyContent, new { cols="100"})%>
```

Apparently, the TextAreaFor takes care of the qualified naming job, hence making the DefaultBinder work properly.